# .NET query of Access database misinterprets dd/mm/yyyy date literal as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sql, vb.net, datetime, ms-access, globalization

Please help me understanding what is happening

I have a visual basic app that returns data from an access database
i want to query a db field with dates with this format "01/12/2015" (Dec 1st)
to do so i have a datetimepicker

I have this record in my DB -  01/12/2015

when i update my code to include it datetimepicker value into a query it won't return nothing, if i put in 12/01/2015 it finds the record with 01/12/2015

my query looks like this:

```
dim dd as date 
dd = datetimepicker.value
qrytxt = "select * from table where [Date] = #" + dd + "#"
```

if i put a msgbox to return qrytxt it returns

```
select * from table where [Date] = #01/12/2015#
```

but it still checks the wrong date against the db...

i also have this Imports System.Globalization and i read something about a CultureInfo but i couldn't put it to work in my query.

Is there anything else i need to include or do ?

Comment: *"I have a visual basic app ..."* - Do you mean a VB.NET application?

Comment: No sorry its windows form , using visual studio 2013

Comment: Can't you just reformat the date in your code before passing it to the DB so that it's `mm/dd/yyyy` format like the db expects it? Like, in VB with `qrytxt = "SELECT ... [Date] = #" + Format(dd, "mm/dd/yyyy") + "#"`

Comment: well i guess i could , but why is this happening? i'm portuguese and both db and app are in portuguese language ... it should't expect the mm/dd/yyyy format...am i right?

Comment: If you want @JNevill to be notified of your comment you need to "@reply" to them like I did earlier in this sentence. Details [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work).

Comment: The Access db engine will interpret `where [Date] = #01/12/2015#` to mean Jan 12th.  Perhaps you intend 01/12/2015 to mean Dec 1st.  But this is confusing because your question says 01/12/2015 represents Jan 1st, which is not reasonable.

Comment: I believe that in your VBA because you declared `dd` as a date that it has defaulted to your locales preferred date format of `dd/mm/yyyy`, but I'm guessing that Access, at least the way you are connecting to it, doesn't care about your locale, and is instead just wanting to receive `mm/dd/yyyy` format. This is typical for databases to have a default date format that it prefers and it's you that must conform to it. For better or worse.

Comment: Use *yyyy-m-d* format for the literal date value in your query.  For example, if you want to target Jan 12, 2015 ... `WHERE [Date] = #2015-1-12#`

Comment: @JNevill my db has format dd/mm/yyyy in the field properties... this is why i didn't understand it... even tryed not to declare dd as date but doesn't work too.what would be the best way to work with this? in my query i mean

Comment: The format is only for display. It doesn't affect the value itself which is based on a Double numeric value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just force a format on your date value to create a string expression for the date:

```
Dim dd As Date 
dd = datetimepicker.value
qrytxt = "select * from table where [Date] = #" + dd.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#"
```

Comment: probably not the most correct approach as Gord said but it works for me .Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> why is this happening?

It's happening because the date literal is ambiguous and does not match the format that the Access Database Engine *assumes* for ambiguous date literals.

Using a date literal with dynamic SQL is the wrong approach anyway. The DateTimePicker returns a true `System.DateTime` value (which is always unambiguous) so you should just use that as part of a *parameterized query*:

```
Using cmd As New OdbcCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM Clients WHERE DOB = ?", conn)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value.Date
    MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
End Using
```